# Additional voices to a ASP.NET web app

Tags: asp.net, text-to-speech, sapi

I have a web application that uses SAPI to do TTS. I run it on Windows Server 2003 that has MS Sam installed by default.

I understand that there are a number of 3rd party companies that sell voices. For a commercial application, which of these companies offer licenses that don't charge a lot of money? Do they have API to easily integrate with a ASP.NET app?

I really would like to add more voices to the application.

**EDIT: Anymore answers? Thanks**

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**

Judging by the question and comments it sounds like you have the rendering of the audio file and the delivery to the client down already.

Here's some aditional voices:

- http://www.bytecool.com/voices.htm
- http://www.nextup.com/attnv.html
  Basically resells the [AT&T Natural Voices](http://www.naturalvoices.att.com/). Which is very expensive to [use in a server setting](http://www.wizzardsoftware.com/att_server_overview.php).
- https://www.cepstral.com/cgi-bin/store/home reading they're page seems to indicate that a license to play the rendered files over the phone can cost as little as 100 dollars for 2 concurrent ports. Their internet licensing model seems to be based on the SOAP service they offer via [voiceforge.com](http://www.voiceforge.com) but the fact that the pricing page is not done yet seems to indicate this service is still being built.
- http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=5e86ec97-40a7-453f-b0ee-6583171b4530&displaylang=en

Which leaves the L&H voices found on the bytecool.com site or the additional 5 SAPI voices offered in the SDK (setup pack for just the voices linked on bytecool.com).

The AT&T and Cepstral voices sound the best though you pay alot for them.

Changing the rendered voice should be as easy as setting the `Sapi.SpVoice.Voice` property.

Comment: Marijn - My web application creates audio files. I need to add voices on the server. For a end user, it's just a mp3 file like any other file.

Comment: Excellent, i smelled a crappy client side SAPI implementation :). I don't quite get the question then though. It sounds like you have the creation of the mp3's done. Changing the voice should be as easy as setting the `Sapi.SpVoice.Voice` property.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear enough. I do not have any voices installed on the Win Server 2003 (it ships with the default MS Sam voice but I would like to add more). Since this is a commercial application (ie., users pay for getting the audio files) which companies provide free/affordable voices that can be easily integrated with ASP.NET app. Of the companies you listed, correct me if I am wrong, but I don't believe that NextUp and Cepstral offer free voices for commercial use. From the bytecool link, is the L&H TruVoice and other voices free?

Comment: The MS link points to Speech SDK download. I assume this is already a part of the .NET 3.5 Framework that I have installed on the Win Server 2003. Why would I need this download?

Comment: It might very well be installed but the SDK comes with a total of 5 free SAPI voices so i don't think it is. The bytecool page seems to link to an installer of JUST these 5 additional voices though. The L&H voices are also Free. The nextup/cepstral are 23 to 35 dollars per voice which depending on your definition could be affordable. Once installed you should not have to change anything other then selecting the right voice prior to saving it to mp3.

Comment: I am not delighted with MS voices as they sound very robotic :( I did contact nextup/cepstral and although individual licenses cost 23 dollars, the license for commercial use is far beyond my reach. Have you had experience with voices in a commercial environment? If so, your input will really be valuable. I will checkout the licensing for L&H voices.

Comment: My experience with TTS is non-comercial: i.e never had the need to redistribute rendered voices. Would love to hear the response you got from cepstral and nexgen (see also my updated post) would be very good to know.